# Does moving a varchar column to a different table and later using a join improve performance?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-optimization

We have a table with 150 million rows, and one of the columns is still varchar (128 symbols), we optimized every other column to tinyints and similar to reduce size. We're trying to improve the performance further. Would moving the column to another table and using a join when selecting something have any performance issues? there are around 500 unique varchars at the moment, and it shouldn't exceed growth of around 100-200/year, so in theory it should decrease the size of the table drastically.

Comment: It depends. Please elaborate your schema, queries you're optimizing for, and any constraints you have (e.g. hardware capacity). Having these details would help to provide more accurate answers.

Comment: It depends on the queries you want to improve performance for.

Comment: I rephrased my question but forgot the title.. It's a tracker table so very heavy writes, 6 column index, which should reduce the size drastically if I would move the nly varchar column, right?. I'm more interested if the select queries would have a performance hit with a join? This would be the only join.

Comment: If you have no join on this column, leave this poor column alone, its Ok, don't move it.

Comment: It depends on the characteristics of the queries. Joining many rows will harm your performance hard, but maybe it's just necessary for a single record that could have been reduced a way faster beforehand with a separated smaller table. It really depends very much on the queries you're running. Have a look at `vertical partitioning` to get an idea when it is advantageous.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how long those strings are.  Just because the string is defined as `varchar(128)` doesn't mean that it contains that many characters.  A `varchar` is going to contain a length (either one or two bytes) and then the data.  In this case, the length is 1 byte.

So, if your strings are very short, then an integer used for mapping to another table might actually be bigger.

If your strings are long -- say 100 characters -- then replacing them with a looking will be smaller.  And, this might actually have a significant impact on the data size (and hence on performance).

The `join` itself should add little to the cost of a query, particularly if the `join` key is a primary key.  In fact, because the data in the larger table is smaller, such queries might run *faster* with the `join`.

What you should do depends on your data.

Comment: the varchar field is often >50chars. We should probably update it

Comment: @PaaPs . . . Then a reference might noticeably reduce the size of data.